# What are the permissions needed to update Active Directory users in PowerShell and Power Automate Desktop flows

Tags: powershell, active-directory, power-automate-desktop

My ultimate goal is to update different property values in Active Directory (AD), like Display Name, First Name, Last Name, Office, and others, either using Set-ADUser in PowerShell or the AD Update User Info action in a Power Automate Desktop (PAD) flow.

The problem is both ways give me an "Insufficient access rights to perform the operation" message in PowerShell or the "Access Denied" message in PAD.

I am using a Service Account with the delegated tasks of "Create, delete, and manage user accounts", along with "Read all user information".

With the service account I am able to connect to AD and read no problem (Get-ADUser in PowerShell and Get user info in PAD). I just cannot update a user's information.

So, any help with what I can try for permissions on the service account to be able to update AD users will be very appreciated!